# Unexpected symbol error when trying to run a function

Tags: r

Im trying to run the function below but I get:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"MMod<-function (Pmat, cycle, n, Init, halfcycle=F, measure, discount=.03)
{cumul<-0 i"


MMod<-function (Pmat, cycle, n, Init, halfcycle=F, measure, discount=.03)
{cumul<-0 i<-1 istate<-Init m<-measure*cycle
if (halfcycle) {cumul<-0.5*(Init%*%m)} while (i <= n)
{   istate<-istate%*%Pmat   imeasure<-istate%*%m   cumul<-cumul+imeasure
#print(paste(c(i,round(istate,2),cumul)))   i<-i+1
m<-m*(1-discount*cycle)
}
if (halfcycle) {cumul<-cumul - 0.5*imeasure} return(cumul)}
```

then I get more erros but I believe that is the key to run it.

Comment: Without being able to test.... My guess is that cumul <- 0 and i <- 1 need to be on separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R (among many programming languages) is very particular about this: different expressions must be separated either by a newline or a semi-colon. Try this:

```r
MMod <- function(Pmat, cycle, n, Init, halfcycle = FALSE, measure, discount = 0.03) {
  cumul <- 0
  i <- 1
  istate <- Init
  m <- measure * cycle
  if (halfcycle) {
    cumul <- 0.5 * (Init %*% m)
  }
  while (i <= n) {
    istate <- istate %*% Pmat
    imeasure <- istate %*% m
    cumul <- cumul + imeasure
    #print(paste(c(i,round(istate,2),cumul)))   i<-i+1
    m <- m * (1 - discount * cycle)
  }
  if (halfcycle) {
    cumul <- cumul - 0.5 * imeasure
  }
  return(cumul)
}
```